# How to tell if already has audio focus?

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I have an audio playback Android App which politely does a requestAudioFocus() when it starts playing, and abandonAudioFocus() when it stops.  Sometimes the user will want to playback a different file in my app, I'd like to be able to check if I already have the audiofocus so that I don't do a request from myself.  Looking at documentation for AudioManager I'm not seeing a way to do this -- seems like a rather blatant omission.  Does anybody know if there is a way to determine if a service already has the audio focus before calling request?

Comment: Well, the only answer I've come up with is to track it myself if I want to know whether I have the focus or not.  Sure seems like a hasAudioFocus() method would be a no-brainer to add to AudioManager...